# Mysql Null values sqoop import to hive

Tags: mysql, null, hive, sqoop

I have a table in mysql with some columns have null values. I want to sqoop import the table to hive. 
When I do sqoop import I am getting all null values in the columns that have null in the mysql table.

What I want is if the column value in mysql is null then the same column value in Hive to be empty not null

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using:

- `--null-string <null-string>` The string to be written for a null value for string columns
- `--null-non-string <null-string>` The string to be written for a null value for non-string columns

Add these tag to replace null values of MySQL to any value you want.

For example, for replacing null with empty values, add these tags in your command

```
 --null-string '' --null-non-string ''
```

Comment: I have tried your option --null-string ' ' but still the hive table has null in the columns

Comment: @Active_user I am sorry I missed your comment at that time. It's working fine at my end. If you are still not able to able to solve it please share your IMPORT command.

Comment: The issue was with parquet format not accepting  `--null-string '' --null-non-string ''`

Comment: I used spark to convert all nulls as empty